# Macro For Conditional Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

Can anybody tell the macro for conditional formatting, like I have an excel which contains 2 worksheets, I need to format data in column M which is in % as pet the criteria given in another worksheet say Target(E,F columns).

Eg. If value of M5 is less than E3 then Background color of M5 should be red, if it is greater than F3 then M5 should be green and if value of M5 is in between E3 & F3 then color of M5 should be amber.

Pls help with this.

Comment: Plenty of answers related to conditional formatting. Find what best fits your needs and if you get stuck post your code for assistance. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=excel+conditional+formatting

Comment: I tried using if else function but no gain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `E3` in `Sheet2` is 50 and `F3` is 60,

[image]

```
Sub highlightcol()
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, "M") < Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E3") Then
        Cells(i, "M").Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf Cells(i, "M") > Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F3") Then
        Cells(i, "M").Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Else
        Cells(i, "M").Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This simple code highlights all values in `Column M` based on conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot..it works...can I get one more help pls....In the same worksheet, I have 5 columns, 1st column contain the file name. I hv to split the file name in team,branch,location and week wise in preceding columns. after that hv to apply filter and first filter on week from A to Z then on location A to Z. I hv 3 weeks data in each report. At the end of the last row, I want to add 3 more row of respective weeks and sum the respective weeks data.

Comment: each column for last 3 rows of weeks have different formula to be calculated from respective column... pls suggest

Comment: @Will This seems to be a different question. Please mark this answer as correct to make this question resolved. I suggest you to open another question with the complete details.